# Facing an issue while displaying output to the console

Tags: java

I'm trying to store input in the array indoor_games and output it to the screen, but when I'm executing the code, it abruptly ends the execution after accepting 1 value.

```java
package games;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Indoor{
  String name;
  Indoor(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  public void display(){
    System.out.println(this.name);
  }
}
class Outdoor{
  String name;
  Outdoor(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  public void display(){
    System.out.println(this.name);
  }
}
class Slip20{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    System.out.println("Enter number of Players in Indoor Games: ");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    Indoor[] indoor_games = new Indoor[size];
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        name = sc.next();
        indoor_games[i] = new Indoor(name);
      }
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        indoor_games[i].display();
  }
}
```

**Updated code with nextLine added but still the same problem:**

```java
class Slip20{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    System.out.println("Enter number of Players in Indoor Games: ");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); //To consume the newline character
    Indoor[] indoor_games = new Indoor[size];
      for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
        name = sc.nextLine();
        indoor_games[i] = new Indoor(name);   
      }
      for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
        indoor_games[i].display();
  }
}
```

**Output(Command Line)**

D:\Docs Dump\School stuff\JAVA\Java slips>java games.Slip20

Enter number of Players in Indoor Games:

3

Neeraj

D:\Docs Dump\School stuff\JAVA\Java slips>

As you can see, the scanner only accepts "Neeraj" and the program ends

execution.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do, and based upon the code that you have, why are you expecting it to do it?

Comment: You need to consume the end of line which you are not doing by solely calling `next()` and `nextInt()`. Fix it by calling `nextLine()`.

Comment: Tried that but still I'm not able to accept more than one value.

Comment: Just a general advice. You coding style looks much and much outdated. If you are learning Java now, make sure you get used to latest Java 8 standards.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your description of "it abruptly ends". How does it end? Does it throw you back into the command line? Does it display any error message? Just it just appear to hang by showing just blank space?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Yes, my bad. I have made changed to the post.

Comment: Using your updated code I couldn't reproduce the issue. It ran fine.

Comment: I really don't know whats wrong then, I'm executing the same exact code.

Comment: Add some println statements all over the code to trace the flow of execution and find out exactly where it's failing.

Comment: I hadn't compiled the package and that was the problem, that's why whatever changes I was making weren't reflecting in the program. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

just replace sc.next() by sc.nextLine()

Comment: And then you'll have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/3419894). Not to mention that `name` is a String.

Comment: Why the extra step Indoor indoor = new Indoor(name); indoor_games[i] = indoor?

Comment: putting indoor in a variable let him to store the instance and usit to call the display method

Comment: But you can directly do that with indoor_games[i].display(), I feel its unnecessary..

Answer (score 0):

This is because nextLine() required. But be aware use it, documentation say that:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input
>        * that was skipped.
>
> This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line
>        * separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next
>        * line.

Known that you should use before loop and problem will be solved.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter number of Players in Indoor Games: ");
int size = sc.nextInt();
Indoor[] indoor_games = new Indoor[size];
sc.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please write a name:");
    indoor_games[i] = new Indoor(sc.nextLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for the answers and help. It was actually a compilation problem, I was compiling the package in a wrong way. It's working now.